# How to create a post method for related entities using DTOs in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a crud for two related entities, I am new to Web APIs. I am not really sure if I am doing it right.

Here are my two models:

`Estado` is my parent model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;    

namespace AppEstados.Models
{
    public class Estado
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }    
        [Required]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }    
        public ICollection<Municipio>? Municipios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Municipio`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;    

namespace AppEstados.Models
{
    public class Municipio
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public  string? Nombre { get; set; }
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public Estado? Estado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`EstadoDto`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppEstados.DTOs
{
    public class EstadoDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MunicipioDto`:

```
using AppEstados.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppEstados.DTOs
{
    public class MunicipioDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public string? Estado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MunicipioController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AppEstados.Data;
using AppEstados.Models;
using AppEstados.DTOs;

namespace AppEstados.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MunicipioController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MiContext _context;

        public MunicipioController(MiContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Municipio
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MunicipioDto>>> GetMunicipios()
        {
            var municipio = await _context.Municipios.Select(x => new MunicipioDto
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Nombre = x.Nombre,
                EstadoId = x.EstadoId,
                Estado = x.Estado.Nombre
            }).ToListAsync();

            return municipio;
        }

        // GET: api/Municipio/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MunicipioDto>> GetMunicipio(int id)
        {
            var municipio = await _context.Municipios 
                                          .Include(x => x.Estado)
                                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            if (municipio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var municipioDto = new MunicipioDto()
            {
                Id = municipio.Id,
                Nombre = municipio.Nombre,
                EstadoId = municipio.EstadoId,
                Estado = municipio.Estado.Nombre
            };

            //var municipioDto = MunicipioAdto(municipio);
            return municipioDto;
        }

        // PUT: api/Municipio/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutMunicipio(int id, MunicipioDto municipioDto)
        {
            if (id != municipioDto.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var municipioAmodificar = await _context.Municipios
                                                    .Include(x => x.Estado)
                                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            if (municipioAmodificar == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            municipioAmodificar.Nombre = municipioDto.Nombre;
            municipioAmodificar.Estado.Nombre = municipioDto.Estado;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) when (!MunicipioExists(id))
            {             
                 return NotFound();        
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MunicipioDto>> PostMunicipio( MunicipioDto municipioDto)
        {
            var municipio = new Municipio()
            {
                Nombre = municipioDto.Nombre,
                EstadoId = municipioDto.EstadoId
            };

            _context.Municipios.Add(municipio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetMunicipio", new { id = municipio.Id }, municipio);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Municipio/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMunicipio(int id)
        {
            var municipio = await _context.Municipios.FindAsync(id);

            if (municipio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Municipios.Remove(municipio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        public static MunicipioDto MunicipioAdto(Municipio municipio)
        {
            var municipioDto = new MunicipioDto()
            {
                Id = municipio.Id,
                Nombre =municipio.Nombre
            };

            return municipioDto;
        }

        private bool MunicipioExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Municipios.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

When I do a `POST` request in Postman, I get the following results:

[POST REQUEST TO Municipio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMmSM.png)

As you can see I get a null value, for estado, so I was wondering how to fix that...

When I send a [GE REQUEST TO MUNICIPIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYU1S.png) on Postman, I do get all the values that were inserted.

I know my problem is in my `PostMunicipio` and `GetMunicipio(int id)` methods.

Answer (score 1):

your `PostMunicipio` method never fetches the related `Estado` resource from the db.

You have a few options, the simplest probably being a quick:

```cs
// After awaiting SaveChangesAsync, so that municipo.Id is populated
var municipoToReturn = await _context.Municipios
    .Select(m => new MunicipioDto
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Nombre = m.Nombre,
        EstadoId = m.EstadoId,
        Estado = m.Estado.Nombre
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == municipo.Id);
```

or, if you want to fetch only the name:

```
// After awaiting SaveChangesAsync, so that municipo.Id is populated
var estadoNombre = await _context.Municipios
    .Select(m => m.Estado.Nombre)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == municipo.Id);
municipoDto.Estado = estadoNombre;
```

and, a final option that EF provides:

```cs
await _context.Entry(municipo)
    .Reference(b => b.Estado)
    .LoadAsync();
municipoDto.Estado = municipo.Estado.Nombre;
```

Comment: Holy molly thank you very much... I want to learn more... any book or website to get better at this ?

Comment: Hm, I don't have a book offhand. The main thing to know here is that just creating `new Municipio()` doesn't load any new information, and the `SaveChangesAsync` will only update the primary key (`Id`) on the entity. If you want to fetch any other information, you have to do it explicitly with a query (like in the first 2 examples, "LINQ queries"), or with a call to `Load` (ef-specific method for loading properties of an already-loaded entity)

Comment: (There might be other ways to load data, but those are the 2 that come to my mind for 90%+ of circumstances)

Comment: @AnheruDesu: Mainly look up how to change tracker works. This is the key component you bumped into. Very oversimplified: the change tracker is a cache. It fetches an entity once, remembers it, and then reuses it when it is asked for the same entity again. When you attached your entity, it put it into the cache exactly the way you presented it (i.e. without a nested `Estado`). The cache does not automatically  enrich its own entries, which is why your `Estado` was not being filled in. This is why firing off a new query (thereby skipping the cache) forces the retrieval of all the data you need.